# 2nd Attempt clearTimeout fails to execute

Tags: reactjs, pubnub, cleartimeout

I have an endpoint that publishes a request for an IoT device to send new reading data. I'm utilizing the PubNub platform.

On my first attempt, when I get a success response, my clearTimeout function is properly canceling the timer and does not update state to display an error message. However, every time I try to execute the request a second time, the clearTimeout function fails to stop the timer. I get my success response, but then I also get the timed out response which displays my error message to the user.

```
handleCheckSensor(){
  if(CancelTimeout){
    clearTimeout(CancelTimeout)
  }
  this.setState({displayGraphs: false})
  this.setState({message: null, error: null})
  const user = this.state.user[0]
  this.pubnub.subscribe({
    channels: [user.channel],
    withPresence: true,
  })
  const CancelPubNub = () => {
    this.setState({isCheckingSensor: false, error: "your request timed out. It appears device did not respond."})
    this.pubnub.unsubscribe({
      channels: [user.channel],
    })
  }

  const CancelTimeout = setTimeout(CancelPubNub, 15000);


  this.pubnub.getMessage(user.channel, (message) => {
    clearTimeout(CancelTimeout)
    this.setState({message: message, isCheckingSensor: false})

  }) 

... }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the timeout id `CancelTimeout` outside of this function due to scope isolation. Right now the `CancelTimeout` is local variable, created only for the time this function is running. The good place would be on `this` in the component. Something like `this.CancelTimeout`.

Comment: Thanks Lukasz, initializing the var in the constructor & clearing the timeout in ComponentDidUpdate fixed the issue.